# Amend R Script to read date from two columns

Tags: r

I want to change the following line of R Script code in my current code so the R script finds the mini date from column `RecordDate` and an maximum date as opposed to using `start=c(2018, 5), end=c(2019, 5), frequency=12)`. and second part is to use column `Count` to get our date points for those date as opposed to using `data2 <- ts(c(9,9,14,4,14,15,4,14,17,17,19,16)`. I need to make the R script below more dynamic:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(trend)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
library(Kendall)
#End of first set of commands


#Begin second set of commands
data2 <- ts(c(9,9,14,4,14,15,4,14,17,17,19,16), start=c(2018, 5), end=c(2019, 5), frequency=12)
  mk.test(data2)
  data1X <- c(1:length(data1))
  data1Fit <- lm(data1~data1X)
  data1df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(time(data1)), Y=as.matrix(data1))
  ggplot(data=data1df, mapping=aes(x=date, y=Y, ymin = 0))+geom_point() +
    geom_line(color='blue') +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") +
    xlab("Months") + 
    ylab("Complaints") +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = '%b %y') +
    labs(title = paste("Adj R2 = ",signif(summary(data1Fit)$adj.r.squared, 5),
                       " Slope =",signif(data1Fit$coef[[2]], 5)))
  #End of second set of commands
```

I want to have the ability to make the R Script more dynamic as opposed to using fixed vector dates and data points, as shown in the script above.

Comment: Hi, what is "RecordDate"? Are you referring to a column in a data set you have? Same for "Count". Please provide more information and a reproducible example providing a sample of your data.

Comment: Hi,Yes i am referening to teh column in my data set. Yes the same for Count too. PS how can i upload a sample data set?

Comment: Report Date Count
02/07/2018 2
02/07/2018 3
05/08/2018 4
03/08/2018 5
03/09/2018 6
03/09/2018 3
09/09/2018 1
03/10/2018 2
03/10/2018 1
10/11/2018 2
10/11/2018 1
10/11/2018 1
05/12/2018 1
06/12/2018 1
09/12/2018 1
18/07/2018 1
18/07/2018 1
17/03/2019 2
17/03/2019 4
17/04/2019 5
17/05/2019 3
17/07/2019 3
19/07/2019 3